# copying & selecting a span programmatically in Javascript (with clipboard.js)

Tags: javascript, html, clipboard.js

#### Context

The real free software (GPLv3) application (motivating this question) that I am coding is the [MELT monitor](https://github.com/bstarynk/melt-monitor-2015) on github (FWIW, I am at commit [56a83d358d3966eddb55...](https://github.com/bstarynk/melt-monitor-2015/commit/56a83d358d3966eddb55f676ff501d48f51430f3) on February 11<sup>th</sup>, 2016). It is on Linux/x86_64/Debian, Firefox/44, JQuery-2.2.0, JqueryUI 1.11.4, clipboard.js 1.5.8....

A more open (but without code) [related question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/309681/40065) was downvoted on Programmers. So I made a [**JsFiddle example**](https://jsfiddle.net/bstarynk/g2notLd7/) for this very question, but that JsFiddle example is probably very wrong.

> I have a (dynamically generated) HTML document with some `<span>`-s of  `class='momitemref_cl'` like `<span class='momitemref_cl'>this</span>` etc... (the inside content of such spans is always a single word like `this`, actually some variable name or identifier in some DSL of mine). My goal is to have a ***dynamically generated* menu** for each such spans to enable some *operations* on them, in particular: **hilight** every occurrence of that word, and **copy & select** the word to the browser's and desktop's clipboard.

There are many questions here about *copying to the clipboard in Javascript*, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript) one. Several of them mention Zeno Rocha's [clipboard.js](http://clipboardjs.com/) which I am trying to use.

#### Code with explanation

To explain some of the JsFiddle: I am creating the [JQueryUI menu](https://jqueryui.com/menu/) with

```
// make a menu for the given span
function make_menu(spa) {
  console.log("make_menu spa=", spa);
  var name = $(spa).text();
  mom_menuitemcount++;
  var menuid = "menuid_" + mom_menuitemcount;
  console.log("make_menu name=", name, " menuid=", menuid);
  $maindiv.after("<ul class='mommenu_cl' id='" + menuid + "'>"
               + "<li class='ui-state-disabled'>* <i>" + name + "</i> *</li>"
    // the text inside the following <li> matters
    + "<li>Hilight</li>" + "<li>Copy</li>" + "</ul>");
  var mymenu = $('#' + menuid);
  mymenu.menu({
    select: function(ev, ui) {
      var uitem = ui.item;
      var utext = uitem.text();
      console.log("mymenu-select ev=", ev, " ui=", ui, " name=", name,
        " uitem=", uitem, " utext=", utext);
      switch (utext) {
        case "Hilight":
          $maindiv.find(".momitemref_cl").each(function(ix, el) {
            var etext = $(el).text();
            console.log("hilighting el=", el, " etext=", etext);
            if (etext == name) {
              $(el).toggleClass("momhilight_cl");
            }
          });
          break;
        case "Copy":
          //// what should go here?
          break;
      };
      setTimeout(200, destroy_menu);
    },
    position: {
      my: "left top",
      at: "bottom left",
      of: spa
    }
  });
  mom_menuitem = mymenu;
  console.log("make_menu spa=", spa, " mymenu=", mymenu);
  return mymenu;
}
```

In the above code, I don't know what to put in `//// what should go here?`; perhaps it might be something similar to:

```
uitem.select();
document.execCommand('Copy');
```

but AFAIU this don't work as expected, and I feel that clipboard operations need the user event (e.g. a mouse click or down) trigerring them.

The clipboard is initialized with

```
$clipboardh = new Clipboard(".momitemref_cl", {
  text: function (trig) {
    console.log("clipboard text trig=", trig);
    /// some code is missing here probably
  };
});
```

I guess (but I am not sure) that the `/// some code is missing here probably` should return the text value of the relevant span.

#### Questions

So I don't know how to copy the span's content to the clipboard (`//// what should go here?` ....) and how to put into the clipboard its text (`/// some code is missing here probably`....)

The full MVCE code is [this JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bstarynk/g2notLd7/)

In other words, **how to use `clipboard.js` from a JQueryUI menu item to copy a `span`'s content to the browser's clipboard ??**

---

Perhaps the entire approach is wrong, and perhaps I should use `contextmenu` (but then, how to customize it only for `span`-s of `class='momitemref_cl'` ?)

To make things even more complex, I actually have in [MELT monitor](https://github.com/bstarynk/melt-monitor-2015) (but not in [this JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bstarynk/g2notLd7/)...) two CSS classes `mom_itemref_cl` & `mom_itemval_cl` that I want to behave likewise.

---

PS. I messed the JsFiddle when copying code here. I updated it, 
https://jsfiddle.net/bstarynk/g2notLd7/132/

NB. I could be satisfied with an answer working only on recent Firefox & Chrome.

Comment: If something is missing in the question, please tell in comments. I will improve it as much as possible

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle with a working menu? It's missing the make_menu function. (had to fix a ``;`` bug first to make it even run >.>)

Comment: Working fiddle here (along with some WIP from me): https://jsfiddle.net/g2notLd7/127/

Comment: @ajm: But how do you handle clipboard copying?

Answer (score 4):

Clipboard.js needs to be attached to the element that triggers the copy event. In your case, this is the `<li>Copy</li>` element inside the `mommenu_cl` menu, which you create dynamically when a `momitemref_cl` is right clicked. You can attach clipboard.js to the Copy `li` dynamically when you create the menu itself. You will also have to destroy the clipboard when you destroy the menu.

First, let's fix the typo in your updated fiddle, on line 87:

```
curmenu[0].stle.left = Math.round(ev.pageY) + 5;
```

Then, remove the clipboard from your DOM's ready handler, we'll move this to the `make_menu` function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $maindiv = $('#maindiv_id');
  // no clipboard initialization here
  console.log("our document ready function");
  ...
});
```

Next, at the top of your script, were you first declare `$clipboardh`, initialize it to `false`. Later, you will be checking to make sure you only attach the clipboard in case it is not currently attached.

```
/// javascript code
var $clipboardh = false;
```

In your `make_menu` function, give your `<li>Copy</li>` element a `class="copy"` attribute so you can easily attach clipboard.js to it, and a `data-clipboard-text` attribute set to the value you want clipboard.js to copy when the element is clicked.

Because the `name` variable contains the text value you want to copy, your menu will look something like:

```
$maindiv.after("<ul class='mommenu_cl' id='" + menuid + "'>" +
        "<li class='copy' data-clipboard-text='" + name + "'>Copy</li>" + 
    "</ul>");
```

Next, just after this code in your `make_menu` function, attach clipboard.js, only if it was not already attached:

```
if ($clipboardh === false){
  console.log("creating the clipboard");
  $clipboardh = new Clipboard('.copy');

  // some optional event handlers for debugging
  $clipboardh.on('success', function(e) {
      console.info('Action:', e.action);
      console.info('Text:', e.text);
      console.info('Trigger:', e.trigger);

      e.clearSelection();
  });

  $clipboardh.on('error', function(e) {
      console.error('Action:', e.action);
      console.error('Trigger:', e.trigger);
  });
}
```

Finally, you will want to make sure you destroy the clipboard when you destroy the menu, by adding this to the bottom of your `destroy_menu` function:

```
$clipboardh.destroy();
$clipboardh = false;
```

[You can find a working fiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/g2notLd7/138/)

Answer (score 3):

Copying from the clipboard from anything other than IE needs to happen on an editable element.  The most common way to handle this is to create a hidden textarea, put the content in the text area and then

```
textArea.select();
document.execCommand('Copy');
```

For IE, you can just use

```
if(window.clipboardData){
    window.clipboardData.setData('Text',
        uitem.innerText);
}
```

I wrote a pretty extensive article explaining how this all works and I have a project on GitHub with the resulting code.

http://blog.dmbcllc.com/cross-browser-javascript-copy-and-paste/

It took me months to sort out all of the conflicting advice available by searching Google because HOW you do this keeps changes as the browsers "mature".

Comment: Would making the span *temporarily* `contenteditable` do the trick?

Comment: Also, are you suggesting that  `clipboard.js` is useless in my case?

Comment: Making the span temporarily editable may work.  I never tried.
I didn't need clipboard.js it for what I was doing.